# Question look like the Ruzsa triangle inequality

Tags: combinatorics

Denote $ X+Y=\{x+y:x\in X,y\in Y\} $ for two non-empty finite sets $ X,Y\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Does the following inequality always hold for any three non-empty finite sets $ A,B,C\subset\mathbb{R}$?
$$ |A|\cdot|A+B+C|\le|A+B|\cdot|A+C|.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not even for $A = B = C$. There is a standard example of a set $A$ such that $|2A| = K|A|$ and $|3A| \geq c K^3 |A|$. See the comments on this answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/160327/20598

Comment: What about the inequality $ |A+B+C|^2\le |B+C||C+A||A+B| $ ?
I once wanted to prove it by the questioned inequality above.
The pretty counterexample doesn't work for this inequality though.

Comment: Not sure about that one.